# writing a single file per loop vs many in python

Tags: python

I have the following script that allows me to log into different routers and run different commands and then it outputs them to a file and this works great except that I get one file for every router I go into.   So what I am looking to do is see if I can get just one file regardless of how many boxes I go into.   I use a host.txt file to define the routers and commands.txt to define the commands I want to run.

```
import telnetlib

user = "user"
password = "password"


#Getting list of Sites to use and logging in
with open('host.txt', 'r') as hostlist:
    host = [line.strip() for line in hostlist]
    for hostname in host:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(hostname,23,30)
        print "Grabbing data from site"
        tn.read_until("Username: ")
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        tn.read_until("Password: ")
        tn.write(password + "\n")
        tn.write("\n")
        tn.write("term length 0\n")
        with open('commands.txt', 'r') as commandlist:
            commands = [line.strip() for line in commandlist]
            for commandcall in commands:
                tn.write(commandcall + "\n")
        tn.write("exit\n")
        outFile = open(hostname + ".txt", "wt")
        outFile.write (tn.read_all())
        outFile.close()
        tn.close()
```

Comment: Well, just use the same filename for your `outFile` and open it in append (`a`) mode. Then you can just append to it with responses from any host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
host = [line.strip() for line in hostlist]
for hostname in host:
```

Then:

```
outFile = open(hostname + ".txt", "wt")
outFile.write (tn.read_all())
outFile.close()
```

So it makes sense that each hostname is going to generate a new file because you're changing the argument of outFile.open() to be each hostname as you loop through.

If you make the argument for open() a static string, this should do what you want. You also want to use "a" to append.

```
outFile = open("RouterLog.txt", "a")
outFile.write (tn.read_all())
outFile.close()
```